# Update /bin/usr/php in CentOS 6

Tags: centos, ssh, php, plesk

I have Plesk 12.5 installed, and it allows you to install multiple versions of PHP to be selectable within hosting spaces (domains), but the issue I've having right now is that the `php` that is being used by the server during SSH commands is much older, and I really need to update it.

Is there a clear way of doing so? Can I use one of the versions that Plesk installed?

Answer (score 0):

To install the latest version of php on your system you would just need to perform a `yum update`. and see whats available from your repositories.

If you need to install a specific version of php then you'd want to utilize `yum list --showduplicates php` to see all available packages.

[php](/questions/tagged/php) [yum](/questions/tagged/yum) [centos](/questions/tagged/centos)

Comment: `yum` says that there are no updates.

Comment: You may need to add an aditional 3rd party to yum then. see [link](https://webtatic.com/packages/php55/)